# I'm getting this error "Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line" does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this error "Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line" does anyone know how to fix it? Here's my script

```cs
private float speed = 2.0f;
public Game#1 character;

void Update () {
        
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            transform.position += Vector3.left* speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            transform.position += Vector3.back* speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Game#1` is not a valid type name in c# ...

Answer (score 2):

C# (and a considerable amount of programing languages) require 'custom names' (i.e. the name of the variables, of the classes, of any thing that you give a name) to obey some specific rules:

- The name can contain only alphanumeric characters - that means only letters (including capitals) and numbers - and the character `_` (underscore)
- The name must start with a letter (it can start with the underscore character too, but I recommend you to avoid names starting with `_`)

So, any other special character (e.g. `#`, `@`, `\`,  (white space) etc.) must not be used in these names.

From your description I see you have a datatype (a class, probably) which has the name `Game#1`. As you can deduct yourself, the name is forbidden and thus you are getting an error.

Some valid names you can give instead: `Game1`, `Game_1` etc.

If you are planning to work a lot on your computer, especially programming stuff, I recommend you always following these rules (naming your folders, files, etc.), even if they are not always that strict, to avoid such errors.

Additionally to these rules, Microsoft recommends using certain [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). Although they are not mandatory, it is a good programming practice to follow them. In time, you will see their usefulness.

As I can see you are confused with the error you are getting. The `#` (hashtag) character is used for something called [preprocessor directives](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24295/preprocessor-directive). The preprocessor is a mini-program that analyze your code before the main compilation and perform some actions. It sees the hashtag and does not know how to interpret it, therefore it throws an error. That's why you are getting a 'preprocessor' error and not a 'naming' one.

Answer (score 0):

The Preprocessor directives are special keywords that starts with a '#' so if you are using 'Game#1' in your class name it may think #1 is a Preprocessor try to change the name.